# File view_ can not select folder to open any files

Tags: blend-files

I Have Bledender installed on two PC's. The main PC can't open any files in Blender. I have Blender 2.82a. The other PC has installed the same Blender and can read files in Blender.

I have uninstalled Blender on the main PC but still does not work. I have used Blender before and it worked when I did some tutorial training.

Can someone please help. I have screen recording of my problem if I can share it with someone who can assist.

Thank you.

My first question. I can not open any folders in Blender File view/window to select a Blender file to open in Blender. I can see all my main folders in my drive where projects are located but can not open any folder in the Blender file view window. When clicking in a folder it does not open to find a project file to open in Blender. Thank you.

Comment: Is this an new problem - are the files you've worked on before? and have you changed blender versions/opened those files with another program?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use Blender 2.80a windows 64. I have access the folder on my drive before. When I did some training/learning. I did manage to open the folder. But today i can only view the main folder in the Blender view file window but I can not open the main file to located the file I worked on before. I noticed this happen before. But I re-installed Blender and I could access the files gain in Blender. I tried to re install today again but it does not work.